# Why doesn't socket.io work well with click events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a very simple html code that just have

```
<div id="colorMe"> Change Me </div>
```

And I'm trying to use socket.io to color this div on all windows when clicked on any window and then when clicked again it changes its color back everywhere and so on.

But it only works the first time only and makes the color blue everywhere but never goes back to white when clicked again.

This is the server code :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('changeColor', function(data){
    io.emit('currentColor',data);
  });

});
```

And this is the javascript part at the html page :

```
var socket = io();

let div = document.querySelector('#colorMe');

socket.on('currentColor',(currentColor)=>{
    div.style.background = currentColor;
});


function changeColor(){
    let color = (div.style.background == 'blue')? 'white' : 'blue';
    socket.emit('changeColor', color);
}

div.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your `changeColor` function to see the value of `color` and another breakpoint in your `currentColor` handler to see if what value `currentColor` is.

Comment: @WillReese I did that it is always blue

Comment: What's the value of `div.style.background`?

Comment: @WillReese the whole thing worked right .. I was writing #336699 instead of blue .. but wrote it here blue for simplicity .. when I wrote it blue at my code it worked .. I can't get yet why hex value didn't work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many browsers set hex values of colors in style attributes to rgb values. Comparing string values of css rules in the style attribute of an html element is risky. Instead, you should just store the color value in another variable instead of referring to the DOM to get that information.

```
let div = document.querySelector('#colorMe');
let myColor = "";

socket.on('currentColor',(currentColor)=>{
    myColor = currentColor;
    div.style.background = currentColor;
});


function changeColor(){
    let color = (myColor == '#336699') ? '#ffffff' : '#336699';
    socket.emit('changeColor', color);
}
```